# function that takes a response variable and a predictor variable and produces a scatterplot with a simple regression line

Tags: r

```
myModel = function(resp, pred){
  linMod = lm(resp~pred)
  myPlot = plot(pred,resp, main="predictor~response")
  abline(linMod, col="red")
  return(myPlot)
}
```

What I want to create is an R function that takes a response variable and a predictor variable as input and
produces a scatterplot with a fitted simple linear regression line.

I then type in `> myModel(c(0.25,0.5,1.0),c(1,2,3))` into the console and then it produces a scatter plot but then I get `NULL` in my console. Why do I get it? Also, is my function correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot` does not return a value, just NULL, so if the intention was to return the plot then replace the `return` line in the body of the function with `recordPlot()` like this:

```
myModel = function(resp, pred){
  linMod = lm(resp~pred)
  plot(pred,resp, main="predictor~response")
  abline(linMod, col="red")
  recordPlot()
}
```

Then we can do this:

```
p <- myModel(c(0.25,0.5,1.0),c(1,2,3))  # perform plotting
dev.off()  # destroy window with plot
print(p)  # restore plot
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `plot` cannot be saved to variables; It can only be plotted directly. Your solution is simple:

```
myModel = function(resp, pred){
  linMod = lm(resp~pred)
  plot(pred,resp, main="predictor~response")
  abline(linMod, col="red")
}
```